# Why are no events showing on calendar after successful query?

Tags: php, pdo, calendar

Like many others I've read about on here, I am trying to make a php/sql based events calendar using an updated form of [Davild Walsh's calendar tutorial](https://davidwalsh.name/php-event-calendar).

It seems I'm connecting to the database just fine, and even populating the $bookings and  $events arrays.  But no events are showing up within my calendar grid.   Can someone please help me see what I'm missing and why the calendar isn't being populated with events? I'm not even doing a complex select statement at this point ... I'm just selecting all events ... successfully ... so I figure it's gotta be some small thing, some minute detail missing or throwing things off.  Any help will be much appreciated.  Reference code below:

Successfully connecting to database with PDO, but posting for reference:

```
 try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=*****;dbname=*****', '*****', '***');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
  exit('Unable to connect to database.');
 }
```

Querying the database like so:

```
$events = array();
 $query = "SELECT * FROM oipevents";
 try {
 $result = $bdd->query($query) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
 } catch (Exception $e) {
     echo "no results";
     exit;
 }
 $bookings = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 foreach ($bookings as $row) {
     $events[$row['event_date']][] = $row;
 }
```

And then drawing the calendar with the following code (note, the calendar with controls shows up just fine, there are just no events showing up):

```
/* draws a calendar */
function draw_calendar($month,$year,$events = array()){

    /* draw table */
    $calendar = '<div class="cal_table">';

    /* table headings */
    $headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
    $calendar.= '<div class="cal_table_cell theme_blue_secondary">'.implode('</div><div class="cal_table_cell theme_blue_secondary">',$headings).'</div></div><!-- #cal_table -->';

    /* days and weeks vars now ... */
    $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_this_week = 1;
    $day_counter = 0;
    // $dates_array = array();

    /* row for week one */
    $calendar.= '<div class="cal_table">';

    /* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
    for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
        $calendar.= '<div class="cal_table_cell">&nbsp;</div>';
        $days_in_this_week++;
    endfor;

    /* keep going with days.... */
    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
        $calendar.= '<div class="cal_table_cell"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;">';
            /* add in the day number */
            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';

            $event_day = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$list_day;

            if(isset($events[$event_day])) {
                foreach($events[$event_day] as $event) {
                //  $calendar.= '<div class="event">'.$event['title'].'</div>';
                    $calendar.='<div class="event"><a href="?event='.$event['title'].'">'.$event['start'].' - '.$event['tijdtot'].'</span></a></div>';
                }
            }
            else {
                $calendar.= str_repeat('',2);
            }
        $calendar.= '</div></div><!-- #cal_table_cel -->';
        if($running_day == 6):
            $calendar.= '</div><!-- #cal_table -->';
            if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                $calendar.= '<div class="cal_table">';
            endif;
            $running_day = -1;
            $days_in_this_week = 0;
        endif;
        $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
    endfor;

    /* finish the rest of the days in the week */
    if($days_in_this_week < 8):
        for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
            $calendar.= '<div class="cal_table_cell">&nbsp;</div><!-- #cal_table_cell -->';
        endfor;
    endif;

    /* final row */
    $calendar.= '</div><!-- #cal_table -->';



    /** DEBUG **/
    $calendar = str_replace('</div>','</div>'."\n",$calendar);


    /* all done, return result */
    return $calendar;
}

function random_number() {
    srand(time());
    return (rand() % 7);
}

/* date settings */
$month = (int) ($_GET['month'] ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
$year = (int)  ($_GET['year'] ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));

    if($month < 10){
        $month = '0'.$month;
    }
/* select month control */
$select_month_control = '<select name="month" id="month">';
for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
    $select_month_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $month ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,$year)).'</option>';
}
$select_month_control.= '</select>';

/* select year control */
$year_range = 7;
$select_year_control = '<select name="year" id="year">';
for($x = ($year-floor($year_range/2)); $x <= ($year+floor($year_range/2)); $x++) {
    $select_year_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $year ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.$x.'</option>';
}
$select_year_control.= '</select>';

/* "next month" control */
$next_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 12 ? $month + 1 : 1).'&year='.($month != 12 ? $year : $year + 1).'" class="control">Next Month &gt;&gt;</a>';

/* "previous month" control */
$previous_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 1 ? $month - 1 : 12).'&year='.($month != 1 ? $year : $year - 1).'" class="control">&lt;&lt;    Previous Month</a>';


/* bringing the controls together */
$controls = '<form method="get">'.$select_month_control.$select_year_control.'&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$previous_month_link.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$next_month_link.' </form>';


echo '<h2 style="float:left; padding-right:30px;">'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)).' '.$year.'</h2>';
echo '<div style="float:left;">'.$controls.'</div>';
echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
echo draw_calendar($month,$year,$events);
echo '<br /><br />';
```

Anyone see why the events aren't making it to the calendar?
When I do print_r($bookings) and print_r($events) I can see populated arrays -- so what's up?  Should I post the arrays too for reference?  Ok ...
$bookings array from print_r($bookings):

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => Test Event [event_date]
>   => 2016-07-27 09:30:00 [end] => 2016-07-27 10:00:00 [url] => http://www.auburn.edu [allDay] => false [description] => test event
>   [department] => alumni ) ... )

Events Array from print_r($events):

> Array ( [2016-07-27 09:30:00] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1
>   [title] => Test Event [event_date] => 2016-07-27 09:30:00 [end] =>
>   2016-07-27 10:00:00 [url] => http://www.auburn.edu [allDay] => false
>   [description] => test event [department] => alumni ) ) .. )

Please help, thank you!

Comment: Have you proved that MySQL is not at fault?  If so, remove that tag.

Comment: What happens if you dump the function output? print_r(draw_calendar($month,$year,$events));

Comment: Good question -- it draws the calendar ... with no events.  derp.

Comment: Hmm, also, I'm not sure I have proven that there isn't a flaw with the Mysql - I mean, arrays are being populated, but maybe not correctly, or I'm not dealing with the data right in the fetch or foreach or row assignment.  But I took the tag off all the same -- I think the issue is with the php.

Comment: Hmm, looking into setting that up now ... having an issue connecting to the database using that site ... but if I get it set up, I will post a link.

Comment: Haven't been able to set up a mimic that allows me to query the database, but I think you're right that there's something amiss with how it's handled in the loops.  Any chance the array info I posted can offer us a clue?  The $events array does seem to be organized by event date, where each array within that array is given an event date instead of the generic [0], but then it seems there is another level within that.  Oy, this is what I get for being a novice and only ever learning enough php to just get by.  Thanks for your help so far, amigo!

Comment: @user3147770 YetiCGN's answer is correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a faulty array access issue. Your `$events` array has keys with date and time, yet you access it via the `$event_day` variable, which has no time component. Further, you piece the date string together on your own and the date is not zero-padded, so it would look for the '2016-8-1' array key and wouldn't find it, because your database results say '2016-08-01'.

For further debugging, put the following in the `else` part of `if(isset($events[$event_day])) {` and you will see what happens:

```
echo $event_day . ' key not found in ' . print_r(array_keys($events), true);
```

Comment: Thank you! Any chance you would be willing to offer a suggestion of how to write the code correctly?  No worries if not, gonna go ahead and mark this as correct and award the bounty and all.  But it would be much appreciated.  Either way this definitely points me in the right direction -- super thanks!

Comment: Well, for one you could do `foreach ($bookings as $row) {
     $date = substr($row['event_date'], 0, 10);
     $events[$date][] = $row;
 }` and then calculate a correct ISO-8601-formatted date for `$event_day` instead of concatenating its parts. Since you have used a combination of `date` and `mktime` already, I'm sure you can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, finally got it going with that foreach statement - didn't need to change the $event_day :-)